# How to commit code for a second time on terminal

Tags: git, github, terminal, bitbucket

I have committed a code into my branch, no one has written anything in it. Do I just **git add** then **git commit -m ''** and then **git push** as usual or do I need to do something else?

Comment: "no one has written anything in it" Can you elaborate?

Comment: No one has made changes to my code

Comment: I am the only one who writes in this repository, this project, whatever you want to call it. No one has written over my code and there are no other commits. Therefore there were no merges. I am wondering how should I send my added features to the repository.

Comment: @ЗлаткоУшев Did you try to push? Did you get an error? Consider `git push --dry-run` to see what *would* happen without actually doing it.

Comment: no, I am afraid that I will make a mistake, so just pushing is the correct practice ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To commit code for the second time you just run:

```
git add .
```

That will stage all the changes you made including new files. Then commit these changes:

```
git commit -m "your message for this commit"
```

And finally push them using:

```
**git push --set-upstream origin master**
```

*Note*: git push shows error "fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

```
git push --set-upstream origin master
```

"

Note that you can run `git  status` command to display the state of your working directory.

Comment: Why doesn't git push --set-upstream origin master work for me?
It responds
```error: src refspec master does not match any.```
```error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/karagiannis/TeX.git'```

Answer (score 0):

You seem that you want to be sure what are you going to push to the distant branch before doing it.
One way of doing it could be:

1. Fetch the changes from your remote repository to update your local repository:

   ```
   git fetch
   ```
2. Display the commits that are not pushed yet to your distant branch, generally `origin/branch_name`:

   ```
   git log origin/branch_name..
   ```
3. Once you're happy with your changes, push them to your distant branch:

   ```
   git push
   ```